# Issue running query based on SELECT statement with MySQL and PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database with two tables

- userlists
- subtasks

A parent can have many children. A child can only have one parent. If a parent exists with at least one child, one DELETE statement should run. If no child exists a different DELETE statement should run. I have the following:

```
try {
    $del_id = $_GET['del_id'];

    $select = "SELECT count(parentID) FROM subtasks WHERE parentID = :del_id";
    $select = $pdo->prepare($select);
    $select->bindParam(':del_id', $_GET['del_id']);
    $result = $select->fetchAll();

    if($result >= 1) {
        $delete = "DELETE userlists, subtasks FROM userlists INNER JOIN subtasks ON userlists.listID = subtasks.parentID WHERE listID = :del_id";
        $delete = $pdo->prepare($delete);
        $delete->bindParam(':del_id', $_GET['del_id']);
        $delete->execute();
        header("Location: loggedin.php");

    } else {
        $delete = "DELETE FROM userlists WHERE listID = :del_id";
        $delete = $pdo->prepare($delete);
        $delete->bindParam(':del_id', $_GET['del_id']);
        $delete->execute();
        header("Location: loggedin.php");
    }
}
```

If I have a parent with at least one child, the first DELETE statement is running as expected. If there is no child however, it appears that the entire code is trying to run the first DELETE statement and just returned to loggedin.php which subsequently does not delete the parent because there is no child.

Is there a specific reason the second query is not running?

Comment: try to change `if($result >= 1) ` to `if(count($result) >= 1) `

Comment: That worked like a champ. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you var_dump `$result` you'll see it is an array. As it's set, it will equal 1, or true. Try `if(count($result) >= 1)` and see if that helps.

Comment: That worked like a champ. I think Masivuye posted his answer first but you offered some additional context.

Comment: i actually posted first (i think), but went back in to edit and add backticks etc :-P

Comment: Well alright then. As soon as it lets me accept your answer I will do it. 7 minutes away!

Comment: Thanks @MasivuyeCokile Will do :)